# Scheme lambda and let errors

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

A beginner in scheme.. trying out the following code to test the equivalence of lambda and let

```
(lambda (x y)
  (+ x y)
  10
  (* x 2))

(let ((k 10)
      (y (* 2 k)))
  (+ k y))
```

the output is

```
#<procedure>
. . k: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The first expression looks quite broken. It adds `x` and `y` and forgets the result. The only thing the expression actually does is doubling `x`, because only the value of the last expression is returned from a function.

Comment: A let-binding is not equivalent to a lambda, it's equivalent to a lambda applied to an argument. `(let ((x e)) body)` <=> `((lambda (x) body) e)`.

Answer (score 0):

Scheme's `let` has two restrictions.

1. The variables defined by `let` are not visible to the body of subsequent definitions.
2. The variables defined by `let` are not visible to the body of the definition itself.

The first restriction applies to your example.

```
(let ((k 10)
      (y (* 2 k)))
  (+ k y))
```

In this example `k` and `y` are defined in the same `let`. The body of `y` does know know `k`. In order to make `k` visible to the body of `y`, you have to use two `let` expressions.

```
(let ((k 10))
  (let ((y (* 2 k)))
    (+ k y)))
```

In order to avoid this kind of nesting, Scheme provides the `let*` alternative.

```
(let* ((k 10)
       (y (* 2 k)))
  (+ k y))
```

If you read the specification of `let*`, you should consider also reading the specification of `letrec`, which is eliminates the second restriction.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the equivalent `lambda` construction to

```
(let ((k 10))
  (let ((y (* 2 k)))
    (+ k y)))
```

is

```
((lambda (k)
   ((lambda (y)
      (+ k y))
    (* 2 k)))
 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The bindings in `let` cannot be used before the body of the `let` form. Thus you need to define `k`:

```
(define k 99)

(let ((k 10)
      (y (* 2 k))) ; the k here is not the one in the same `let`
  (+ k y))
; ==> 208
```

`let` is just syntax sugar for a called anonymous procedure. It's equal to this:

```
((lambda (k y)
   (+ k y))
 10
 (* 2 k))
```

With this syntax is perhaps more obvious that `k` cannot be the one assigned to `10`? There is another syntax called `let*` and it lets you use the previous bindings:

```
(let* ((k 10)
       (y (* 2 k))) ; the k here is not the one in the same `let`
  (+ k y))
; ==> 30
```

It's equal to nested anonymous procedure calls:

```
((lambda (k)
   ((lambda (y)
      (+ k y))
    (* 2 k)))
 10)
```

Here it's easy to see the `k` in `(* 2 k)` is the one bound to `10`.